# neo4j heroku restore from url

Tags: heroku, neo4j

I am trying to import data from a newer version of neo4j to an older version, inside my heroku. When I restore from url, it seems like nothing happens. I am using a newer version in local. Is it possible that, this version difference preventing my restore?